# How to include a CSS file in an XSL file

Tags: css, xml, xslt

I wish to add styling to an XSL document through CSS. However, my previous attempts at this have had no success.

Here's the relevant section from the XSL file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                version="1.0">
<xsl:include href="http://bootswatch.com/sandstone/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>News | Endeavour Explorers</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" 
              href="../resources/img/logo200.png"/>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {padding: 63px 0 63px 0;} 
            a[name] {
               padding-top: 40px; 
               margin-top: -40px; 
               display: inline-block; 
               /* required for webkit browsers */}
            @media print{body {margin-top: -63px;}}
        </style>
    </head>
```

And here's the link to [the whole XSL file](http://eastwightendeavour.org.uk/news.xsl).

Here's [the .xml file](http://eastwightendeavour.org.uk/news.xml).

Comment: Asked and answered. You are not trying to "add styling to an XSL document". You are trying to "add styling the HTML output of an XSLT transform." You need to put a `<link>` inside the `<head>` element to bring the CSS into the HTML.

Answer (score -1):

Your XSL file must have at least one `<xsl:template>` element matching your input XML to do something.

You should not include the CSS file in your XSL file - the XSL processor does not know how to process CSS, instead you should output a `<link>` element in the resulting XML referencing the CSS.

Something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
            version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>News | Endeavour Explorers</title>
            <link rel="shortcut icon" 
                 href="../resources/img/logo200.png"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet"   
                 href="http://bootswatch.com/sandstone/bootstrap.min.css"  type="text/css">
            <style type="text/css">
                body {padding: 63px 0 63px 0;} 
                a[name] {
                   padding-top: 40px; 
                   margin-top: -40px; 
                   display: inline-block; 
                   /* required for webkit browsers */}
                @media print{body {margin-top: -63px;}}
            </style>
       </head>
       . . . .
```